# Modifying 1GP Managed components in an Unlocked Package

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

I would like to make changes to the visible fields of a 1gp Managed FieldSet in my 2gp Unlocked package.

My 1gp Custom Object `pkg__Object__c` contains FieldSets `pkg__FieldSet1` and `pkg__FieldSet2`.
My 2gp Unlocked Package makes the relevant updates to `pkg__FieldSet1` and `pkg__FieldSet2`

My folder structure is therefore:

`pkg__Object__c/
    fieldSets/
        pkg__FieldSet1.fieldSet-meta.xml
        pkg__FieldSet2.fieldSet-meta.xml`

Upon installation (or package creation `force:package:version:create`) I receive the error:

> 1) Cannot add component of type:FieldSet named:pkg__FieldSet1 subjectId:0IX26000000DDu1 to another package because it is an installed component., Details: package.xml: Cannot add component of type:FieldSet named:pkg__FieldSet1 subjectId:0IX26000000DDu1 to another package because it is an installed component.

The error is quite clear, I cannot do this because the FieldSet is installed in another package. Does this mean that I am unable to make changes to 1gp Managed components in a 2gp Unlocked Package and that I will have to revert to deploying unpackaged metadata to achieve that? Or, am I missing a trick?